# Ruby uninitialized constant Pipl::Person (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api-platform.com

I am trying to integrate the Pipl API into my ruby on rails application. I am using ruby version 2.3.4 and rails 4.2.5. As a reference i looked at 
[this site](https://docs.pipl.com/reference/#using-search-parameters)
and copied the ruby version of the code directly from it into a ruby file. When I run the ruby file in the terminal i get the error:

```
`<main>': uninitialized constant Pipl::Person (NameError)
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the code snippet that I used:

```
require 'pipl'

person = Pipl::Person.new
person.add_field Pipl::Name.new(first: 'Clark', last: 'Kent')
person.add_field Pipl::Address.new(country: 'US', state: 'KS', city: 
'Smallville')
person.add_field Pipl::Address.new(country: 'US', state: 'KS', city:  
'Metropolis')

response = Pipl::client.search person: person, api_key: 'myKEY' #I used my actual key here

puts "#{response}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to require the file which contains the `Pipl::Person` class. Do you have a link to the source code for the Pipl library/gem?

Comment: Please ensure you have added `piplapis-ruby` to your Gemfile and not `pipl` (which seems to be a completely undeveloped gem)

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm pretty new to ruby on rails...can you tell me how to do that? I tried doing what this site suggested: https://docs.pipl.com/docs/code-libraries which was to run "bundle install piplapis-ruby" but I get an error stating "ERROR: "bundle install" was called with arguments ["piplapis-ruby"]"

Comment: @Kris I'm not sure I just did "gem install pipl" assuming that was fine

Comment: @jim in the project there is a file called `Gemfile`. Open this file and add `gem 'piplapis-ruby`. Then open a terminal navigate to the root of the project and run `bundle install` then in your project you can try and use the above code (however the require statement is not necessary). All that being said a quick tutorial on rails would probably benefit you drastically. [Michael Hartl's](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) tutorial is still my recommended go to

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you I did what you said and it installed piplapis-ruby. However, when I run the code I get the same error

Comment: There is no `Person` class that I can see in the `piplapis` library: https://github.com/piplcom/piplapis-ruby/tree/master/lib/pipl

Comment: @Kris I can't find it either but i assumed if they had this example on their site than it should work.

Comment: @Kris I guess I just need to add my own Person class. Thanks!

Comment: Their documentation is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the Pipl API without the error, I got my API key through their site and I added `piplapis-ruby` gem just like what was told in the comments above. I imported all of the ruby classes found here: https://github.com/piplcom/piplapis-ruby into my project and pasted the codesnippet.rb file found here: https://github.com/piplcom/piplapis-ruby which was the ruby file you're supposed to execute. There was no need for me to create the Person class.